# How to adjust a fixed height parent div base on its child height?

Tags: css

I have a parent div with a greater fixed height and a child div with a lesser height. What I want to know if it is possible when I insert the child div, can the parent div adjust to the child div height to 200px.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>


.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px auto;
}

.child {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the parent height to auto.

Comment: `height: 400px auto` is invalid

Comment: @Dylan Anlezark But how I to keep parent height initially and let the child height auto resize it.

Comment: when adding the `child` element set the height of the `parent` to *auto*

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Why would this case be needed? there might be solutions depending on what the context is, could you not set the height to auto and use a placeholder child div at a height of 400px until the smaller div is active?

I feel that the context of your situation and desired outcome is important here

Answer (score 0):

Just assign height auto to the parent div. It will automatically take the height of the child div.  And `height: 400px auto` won't work as it is invalid css syntax.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

.child {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is *possible* using the `:empty` pseudo-class BUT current implemenation requires that there be no contents or whitespace in the `.parent` element.

[**`:empty` @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Then we can define a fixed height on the parent and switch this to `auto` if the parent has contents.

Like so:

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: orange;
}

.parent:not(:empty) {
  height: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the height of parent div to 'auto'

> ```
> .parent {
> position: relative;
> height: auto;
> }
> ```

Comment: `height: 400px auto` is invalid!